# How to write setTimeout to run-only-once as a promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I have a couple of user interfaces where different asynchronous processes can be running simultaneously. When some of them finish, they need to do things like refresh some or all of the UI. To avoid the need to run the refresh multiple times, I use a setTimeout function to run the refresh so it runs only once even if 'triggered' from multiple simultaneous processes.  e.g.:

```
var runCleanupTimeout;
function runCleanupOnce() {
    if (runCleanupTimeout) clearTimeout(runCleanupTimeout);
    runCleanupTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        refreshUI();
    }, 250);
}
```

I know I can pass a callback into this also as well as pass the actual timeout as a variable to the function, but I'm starting to work with using Promises in functions that finish at some later time and I'm wondering how to implement such a thing as an abstract promise.
Currently I'm using a single timer (thus the static values and function calls - I seldom need more than one of these in a single UI, but when I do, I create a second variable and a second function with a fixed timeout)

I'd like to be able to write a generic utility-function as a promise so any time I want to do a run-only-once, I just call something like:

```
utilities.runOnce('someTimerId',250).then(
    function() {
        refreshUI();
    }
);
```

I know I could instead use an array/associative array where I specify the id for the 'timer' and use a custom callback type structure. But I'm not entirely sure how this would work in a promise.then() structure. I saw one example using a .bind property but can't find a good reference on what bind() is doing in that case.

Any help to figure this out is appreciated.

Comment: Bonus if anyone knows if [identical] function code is 'testable' as equal so I could auto-generate an ID or otherwise reset active timers based on the callback function. e.g. step through any active timers and if callback function = timer function, reset that one. (I can test this myself though)

Comment: `.bind` is probably `Function.prototype.bind`, and promises are the wrong tool here

Comment: And no, you cannot do an equality check on functions. A function only equals itself

Comment: ok, I thought that might be the case. The bind I saw was in stackoverflow: #39538473 and seemed to bind it to an object. I'd like to be able to call such a thing from inside object methods also, so I thought it might be relevant.

Comment: now that I think on it more, I don't think using a promise is going to be helpful as it's a set-it-and-forget-it type function call. Resetting the timer in another call from another place would effect the original promise.

Comment: Yes, exactly. ...

Comment: at least I figured out where the 'bind' comes in handy. As a utility function, I just wrote it globally by itself when testing. But I wanted to use it to run an instance method. But the instance method uses 'this.*' reference.  EasyPeezy: runOnlyOnce('cleanup', selector.getFolderContents.bind(selector), 250);

Comment: If you have "different asynchronous processes", then you are probably already working with promises. If so, then you may well simply need to exploit [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [Promise.race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises turned out to not be a good solution as a run-once type process only has one discreet resolve